# Uso de Kendo para graficar (problema asignando valores al tooltip y eje X)

Tags: javascript, kendoui

estoy generando un par de gráficas con Kendo, una de barras (column) y una de lineas (Line), las grafica perfecto pero tengo un problema con las etiquetas del eje X,

```
 $("#chartAcumulado").kendoChart({
                chartArea: {
                    height: 200
                },
                dataSource: {
                    data: datos.datos
                },
                series: [{
                    type: "line",
                    field: "total",
                    categoryField: "fecha"
                }],
                seriesColors: ["#009933"],
                tooltip: {
                    visible: true,
                    template: "${ category } - ${ value } Consulta(s)"
                }
            });
```

datos.datos tiene muchos elementos que tienen una fecha y un total, yo quiero que lo que viene en "fecha" se muestre en un tooltip (tal cual como está), pero que en el eje X no aparezca lo mismo, ya que es información extensa y se ve muy mal, como puedo quitar los valores del eje X sin que se pierdan en el tooltip?

Actualmente se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como verán con más datos será aún más problemático

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya lo he podido solucionar así, por si a alguien le sirve:

```
 $("#chartAcumulado").kendoChart({
                chartArea: {
                    height: 200
                },
                dataSource: {
                    data: datos.datos
                },
                legend: {
                     position: "bottom"
                 },
                series: [{
                    type: "line",
                    field: "total",
                    name: "Total de consultas por tramas de media hora"
                }],
                seriesColors: ["#009933"],
                tooltip: {
                    visible: true,
                    template: "#= dataItem.fecha # - ${ value } Consulta(s)"
                }
            });
```